# Resize div to fit screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When the text is added on top,the div moves down and the text on bottom is not visible. I want the divs to resize so that everything fits into container keeping the width and height to 100%.

Is there are any way to do this with CSS or do I need JavaScript?

```css
body,html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
        
.img {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;    
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>Text 1</p>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <p>Text 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: set overflow: auto; in .container class instead of hidden

Comment: The container height should not increase even if the new elements are added?

Comment: Will there only be just two .img element ??

Comment: No the container height should not increase. It should fit to screen without overflowing

Comment: There could be more than two .img element.

Comment: can you add an image with what are you trying to get ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use CSS flex for this.

It could look something like this:

```css
body,html{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #container{
            position: absolute;
            width:100%;
            height: 100%;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .img{
            background: blue;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
            vertical-align: top;    
        }
```

```html
<div id = 'container'>
    <p>Text 1</p>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <p>Text 2</p>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d1kpwt05/)

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery you can achieve like below. Count total number of tags in container div and divide the 100% height among those element. SO all the items will be visible with `overflow:hidden`

Please check below snippet.

```js
var itemLength = $('#container *').length;
$('#container *').css("height",(100/itemLength)+"%");
```

```css
body,html{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img{
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  //height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;    
}
p,img,div{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = 'container'>
    <p>Text 1</p>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <p>Text 2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the height of `.img` to 40%. Because taking 50% height is making it consume the entire height.

```css
        body,html{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #container{
            position: absolute;
            width:100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            background: #ccc;
        }
        .img{
            background: blue;
            width: 100%;
            height: 40%;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;    
        }
```

```html
<div id = 'container'>
    <p class="text1">Text 1</p>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <p class="text2">Text 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This adds scroll bar. The container should fit to screen

Comment: Then you will have to reduce the height of .img divs. Otherwise it won't fit.

Answer (score 0):

Css Code

```
body,html,p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Script

```
$(function(){
var containerHeight= $('#container').height();
var pfirstHeight=$('#container p').eq(0).height();
var pbottomHeight=$('#container p').eq(1).height();
var imgHeight=(containerHeight-pfirstHeight-pbottomHeight)/2;
$('.img').height(imgHeight);
});
```